# Ranking algorithm based spent time and user level

Tags: algorithm, redis, ranking

Think about a game, players are trying to solve problems and every problem is actually means "Level".

Players will see realtime ranking when playing.

RedisIO has sorted set feature, I'll use it.

But I don't know how to score players:

```
PlayerA at 7 level, total game time 80  seconds
PlayerB at 7 level, total game time 65  seconds
PlayerC at 5 level, total game time 40  seconds
PlayerD at 1 level, total game time 200 seconds
```

ranking that I want is just like this

```
1) PlayerB - because level 7 and 65  seconds
2) PlayerA - because level 7 and 80  seconds
3) PlayerC - because level 5 and 40  seconds
4) PlayerD - because level 1 and 200 seconds
```

I tried

```
(timeSpent/level)
```

calculation but it didn't work well when somebody is at lesser level and lesser spent time than other players.

Comment: For these types of things, it's usually best to create a few rules / test cases of how you want your players to be ranked, and then try to create a function that conforms. We have no idea how *you* want *your* ranking system to work.

Comment: Is a player at level 7 always ranked higher than a player at level 6, regardless of time spent?

Comment: Then do as @xeroqu suggested in his comment: use a sort comparer that first compares by level and, if the levels are equal, then compares by time. There's no need to multiply by level or create multiple sublists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can have the following function:

```
score = (level * HUGE_NUMBER) - timeSpent
```

For `HUGE_NUMBER`, you can select a value that is slightly larger than the maximum allowed time to finish a level.

While that might be enough for most cases, I would rather use sorting for this problem to avoid any potential unseen bugs in the ranking algorithm.

Assuming that the `level` of a player is the dominant factor in the ranking, I'd sort all players by `level` in descending order. This may give you something like that (note that it's not the final ranking yet):

```
1) PlayerA - because level 7 and 80  seconds
2) PlayerB - because level 7 and 65  seconds
3) PlayerC - because level 5 and 40  seconds
4) PlayerD - because level 1 and 200 seconds
```

Following that, I'd create sublists of players in each `level` and sort them by `time` in ascending order. In the above example, the second sorting would give you the final correct ranking.

```
1) PlayerB - because level 7 and 65  seconds
2) PlayerA - because level 7 and 80  seconds
3) PlayerC - because level 5 and 40  seconds
4) PlayerD - because level 1 and 200 seconds
```

Comment: I don't want to create multiple sets and handle them, that's why I'm looking for one algorithm. Your function look like will work well.

Comment: You don't need to create multiple sets to handle sorts by 2 dimensions. If you have a stable sort algorithm, you can sort by time first and then level. If you can specify a comparator in your language, you can do it like so `if (a.level == b.level) { return a.time-b.time;} else {return a.level-b.level;}`